# Get html text with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the number from inside a div:

```
<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last">122.7<span class="">8</span></div>
```

I need the 122.7 number, but I cant get it. I have tried with:

```
strings = soup.find("div", class_="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last").string
```

But, there are more than one element and I receive "none".

Is there a way to print the childs and get the string from childs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.getText()`.

For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_html = """
<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last">122.7<span class="">8</span></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "html.parser")
strings = soup.find("div", class_="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last").getText()
print(strings)
```

Output:

```
122.78
```

Or use `__next__()` to get *only* the `122.7`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "html.parser")
strings = soup.find("div", class_="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last").strings.__next__()
print(strings)
```

Output:

```
122.7
```

Answer (score 1):

To only get the first text, search for the tag, and call the [`next_element`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element) method.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last">122.7<span class="">8</span></div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(
    soup.find("div", class_="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last").next_element
)
```

Output:

```
122.7
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use selenium to find the element and then use BS4 to parse it.
An example would be

```py
import selenium.webdriver as WD
from selenium.webdrive.chrome.options import Options
import bs4 as B

driver = WD.Chrome()

objXpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""yourelementxpath""")
objHtml = objXpath.get_attribute("outerHTML")
soup = B.BeutifulSoup(objHtml, 'html.parser')
text = soup.get_text()
```

This code should work.
**DISCLAIMER**
I haven't done work w/ selenium and bs4 in a while so you might have to tweak it a little bit.